# laravel 9 anchor button returning error 404

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, anchor, laravel-9

Im using an achor to click a button to navigate to other page. However, it doesnt work and return a 404 error not found.

My destination blade is : [image]

inventory.blade.php:

```
<a class="d-xl-flex align-items-xl-center" href="{{ url('inventory/add')}}" style="padding-right: 0px;margin-right: 15px;"><button class="btn btn-primary d-xl-flex align-items-xl-center" type="button" style="margin-right: -16px;margin-bottom: 13px;margin-top: 7px;border-color: rgb(162,138,138);background: rgb(0,0,0);padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top: 1px;margin-left: -26px;">ADD PRODUCT</button></a>
```

controller: NavBar.php:

```
public function inv(){
        return view('inventory');
    }
public function invadd(){
        return view('inventory-add');
    }
```

web.php:
[image]

I tried moving the inv() in another controller page and it's not already viewable or accessible by the routing. Is it because of referencing thing? I think my controller cannot access the blades in the resources/views folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using my old code with url and it worked. I just prompt this in terminal:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an anchor tag surronding a button, which doesn't make sense. use either one or the other. That said, you can -

Give your routes a name

```php
Route::get('inventory-add')->name('inventory-add');
```

Then link to it by using the route helper.

```html
<a class="d-xl-flex align-items-xl-center" 
   href="{{ route('inventory-add')}}" 
   style="padding-right: 0px;margin-right: 15px;">
   ADD PRODUCT
</a>
```

You also seem to be trying POST to a route using an anchor tag, which also doesn't make sense. You probably want a form with a submit button which will sent the data using POST with the data from the form.

Comment: What Im trying to make is a button of an "add product" then it will navigate to another page to enter the data. Tried your solution it says "Route [inventory-add] not defined."

Comment: In a console, type `php artisan route:list` to see all your routes. As you are trying to navigate, an anchor tag is best, which you can style as a button, probably by adding the class "btn btn-primary", it looks like you are using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

try again, like this:

```
Route::get('inventory/add')->name('inventoryAdd');
```

> `get()` params corresponding browsers url.

> `name()` You can use it like this: `route('inventoryAdd')`.

Comment: still getting the same error "Route [inventory-add] not defined"

Comment: what's you route namespace?  use namespace.name    like this:  Route::group([
    'prefix'        =>'admin',
    'namespace' => 'App\Admin\Controllers'  , route('admin.inventoryAdd')

Comment: hi im done with the problem, still thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment:

> What Im trying to make is a button of an "add product" then it will navigate to another page to enter the data. Tried your solution it says "Route [inventory-add] not defined."

```
Route::controller(NavBar::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/inventory/add', 'create')->name('product.create');
    Route::post('/inventory/add', 'invadd')->name('product.store');
});
```

Controller method

```
public function create()
{
    return view('inventory-add');
}

public function invadd(Request $request)
{
    // your logic to save the product here
}
```

and in your blade

```
<a href="{{ route('product.create')}}">
   Add product
</a>
```

You are trying to open a link that is assigned to a `post` route, that's why you're getting 404 error, common oversight actually.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted what I want to say. My goal is to navigate the inventory page through side menu, after clicking it, it will show the table of lists and the default page on inventory. There will be the "add product" button in the inventory page, when you click it, it will redirect you to a page where the form really is, in the inventory-add.blade.php.

Comment: Then if you follow along, it's what you're looking for, you just need to know how to read code.

Comment: I tried moving the inv() in another controller page and it's not already viewable or accessible by the routing. Is it because of referencing thing? I think my controller cannot access the blades in the resources/views folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a slash in the front like this:

```
href="{{ url('/inventory/add')}}"
```

For example you are currently on the location:

```
http://example.com/anotherpage
```

And you have this

```
href="{{ url('inventory/add')}}"
```

Clicking on that link, you will go to:

```
http://example.com/anotherpage/inventory/add
```

So you really have to put a slash character in front of `inventory` so that you will go to

```
http://example.com/inventory/add
```

Regardless of your current location on your project.

Comment: hi thank u for this, I'm done with the problem.